# How to pass header in axios request?

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-passport, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to implement Laravel Cashier and Stripe Subscriptions into my Laravel and Vue js SPA. I'm using Laravel Passport and jwt for authentication. I found an article online on how do this.

Whenever I click "Pay" button I get `401 Unauthorized` error and when I click on URL in Network tab it gives error `unauthenticated`.
I think the issue is because I'm not passing the `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth.getAccessToken()` in the headers when trying to access those routes.

Here is the method from the article:

```
loadIntent(){
                axios.get('/api/v1/user/setup-intent')
                    .then( function( response ){
                        this.intentToken = response.data;
                    }.bind(this));
            },
```

Here is what I tried, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
loadIntent(){
                const headers = {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+auth.getAccessToken(),
                };
                axios.get('/api/v1/user/setup-intent', {
                    headers: headers
                })
                    .then( function( response ){
                        this.intentToken = response.data;
                    }.bind(this));
            },
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: If it helps, the issue is likely not related to your Stripe integration, but rather the interface between your Vue app and Laravel backend. As long as you've added your Stripe keys to your `.env` file you should be fine as far as authentication with Stripe goes: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#api-keys. You would only ever provide a bearer token with a Stripe secret key if you were calling Stripe's APIs directly.

Comment: If I post my Controller and Vue component do you think you can have a look? I've really been struggling and I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Have you looked in the network tab of your browser and checked if the header is in the request?

Comment: So I'm getting a new error now. It looks like the header and token is in the request. New error: ```"No such plan: prod_xxx". it was looking for a plan_id instead of a prod_id. I'm trying to create a Subcription and in the article it said in the Stripe dashboard to create a new Product for Subscriptions. Again it should be a plan_id and I'm entering the prod_id. I'm confused about how to setup the Subscription in Stripe.

Comment: At this point I think you might be better off making a new question asking about Stripe so you can get some Stripe experts to help out :)

Comment: Yes, thanks I actually figured it out.